# clone form include dependent fields by vuejs

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have a form in which there should be submitting a price for various health care services. Treatments are already categorized. Now, I want to first select a treatment group from a selector and then select the treatment list for that category in the next selector. When I have just one form on the page, I have no problem. But I need to clone this form and the user can simultaneously record the price of some treatments. In this case, all the second selectors are set according to the last selector for the categories. While having to match their category's selector. I searched for the solution very well and did not get it. My code in vuejs is as follows. Please guide me. Thank you in advance.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div id="treatment_information">
           <div class="col-md-3">
                        <select id="category_name" class="form-control show-tick"
                                v-on:change="getTreatmentList($event)"
                                name="treatment_rates[]category_id" v-model="treatment_rate.category_id"
                        >
                            <option value="0"> -- select category --</option>
                            <option class="form-control main"
                                    v-for="item in vue_categories" :id="item.id+1000" :value="item.id"
                                    :name="item.name">
                                {{ item.name }}
                            </option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <select id="treatment_id" class="form-control show-tick"
                                name="treatment_rates[]treatment_id" v-model="treatment_rate.treatment_id"
                        >
                            <option value="0"> -- select treatment --</option>
                            <option class="form-control main"
                                    v-for="item in vue_treatments" :value="item.id">
                                {{ item.value }}
                            </option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                vue_temp: [],
                vue_categories: [],
                vue_treatments: [],
                vue_category: '',
                //for clone form
                treatment_rate: {
                    category_id: 0,
                    treatment_id: 0,
                    hospital_id: 0,
                    dollar: 'دلار',
                    rial: 'ریال'
                },
                treatment_rates: [],
            };
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.');
            this.getList();
        },
        methods: {
            getList() {
                var self = this;
                axios.get('/vueDashboard/get/categories').then(function (response) {
                    self.vue_temp = response.data;
                    const len = self.vue_temp.length;
                    self.vue_temp.forEach(function (item) {
                        if (self.vue_right.length > 0) {
                            while (self.vue_right[self.vue_right.length - 1] < item['rgt']) {
                                self.vue_right.pop();
                                if (self.vue_right.length == 0)
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                        self.vue_categories.push({
                            'id': item['id'],
                            'name': '---'.repeat(self.vue_right.length) + ' ' + item['name']
                        });
                        self.vue_right.push(item['rgt'])
                        var str = "---";
                    });
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });

                axios.get('/vueDashboard/get/treatments?category=' + JSON.stringify(self.treatment_rates)).then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    self.vue_treatments = response.data;
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
            },
            addForm(event) {
                var self = this;
                self.vue_increment_id[self.vue_counter++]=self.vue_counter;
                console.log(self.vue_increment_id);
                self.treatment_rates.push(Vue.util.extend({}, self.treatment_rate));
            },


        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Hi sparvin, many times people have more attention when the question and the code is short, and the problem well targeted. Sorry I won't read all your code it's too long. Extract from your explanation and this huge part of code, only the heart of your problem. Like that we can study it easily, and you too.

Comment: Maybe some help: you don't need self=this anymore, one can use arrow function and this will be the good this. Good cheers

Comment: Hi Slim. Thank you for taking the time. I deleted all additional codes. I hope you are clearer now.

Comment: Ok, if you want I can give you advices to get a more short and cleaner code. I can't give you any direct answer since I don't understand what is the problem when I read  your explanation. It's not about you, please understand it's just because I give only one minute on your post so I can't make efforts to understand what is not "perfectly clear".

Comment: Please create a method "fetchCategory" and another "getTreathments". It is about separate of concern. mounted will call the two methods.

Comment: remove self=this and use this directly. Use arrow functions inside thens: response => { ...}

Comment: use .catch(console.error) After making these simplifications (and there is other after that), you will see that solution may appear by itself with a clear code ;)

Comment: Learn about computed property basic example: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Basic-Example